# How to combine ActiveRecord objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to combine the results of multiple ActiveRecord objects in Rails. For example, I might make three individual calls to three individual tables, and I want the results combined, and sorted by a common column.

Here's a super basic code example that will hopefully make my question easier to understand:

```
@results1 = Table1.find(:all)  
@results2 = Table2.find(:all)  
@results3 = Table3.find(:all)  

@combined_results_sorted_by_date_column = (how?)
```

As suggested by others, here's one solution to the problem.

```
@combined_results = @result1 + @result2 + @result3
@combined_results.sort! {|x,y| x.date <=> y.date}
```

What if I want to sort by date, but Table3 refers to the "created_on" column as date?

Answer (score 14):

```
@results1 = Table1.find(:all)
@results2 = Table2.find(:all)
@results3 = Table3.find(:all)

@combined_results_sorted_by_date_column =
   (@results1 + @results2 + @results3).sort_by(&:date)
```

What if I want to sort by date, but Table3 refers to the "created_on" column as date?

```
class Table3
  alias_method :date, :created_on
end
```

or simply

```
class Table3
  alias date created_on
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't work with "Tables" but rather objects.

If you think about it this way, it would make no sense to have:

```
@results1 = Users.find(:all)
@results2 = Posts.find(:all)
@results3 = Comments.find(:all)
```

What would the "combined" form of it means?

What you probably want is to combine results from the same kind using different "queries".
Is that it?

Comment: I have a usecase, combined comments, statuses, and commits for a timeline in an issue management application.

Comment: In this case they must all respond to an specific interface or have a way to be mapped into one. The key point is that thinking about it in terms of "database tables" is going to lead you into poor designs. I was not trying to imply you don't use data from different places, just questioning how you approach/think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not going to like this answer, but I would say you might want to revise your database schema. I was in a similar situation, and sorting the results after concatenating them is definitely not the way you want to go.

Comment: I believe you, but could you be more specific of how you handled the situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
@combined_results = @result1 + @result2 + @result3
@combined_results.sort! {|x,y| x.date <=> y.date}
```

While this surely is not be the most efficient code in the world, it might just be what you need.

If some models don't have a date method I suggest you create one.
It is as easy as.

```
def date
  created_on
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@results1 = Table1.find(:all)
@results2 = Table2.find(:all)
@results3 = Table3.find(:all) 

combined = (@results1 + @results2 + @results3).sort { |x, y| x.date <=> y.date }
```

Comment: What if I want to sort by date, but Table3 refers to the "created_on" column as date?  Big thanks!

Comment: You could solve that by adding a "date()" method to Table3 that returns the value of "created_on".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your data volumes are like, but when it comes to sorting, your database will do a better job of it than you ever will using "application layer" code.

Do you need the data returned as an array of model objects seeing as the three tables will probably generate a mixed up array of three distinct model classes ?

Why not use direct-SQL returning rows and columns and have the DB do all the hard work sorting the data ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a mixed array of three different types of ActiveRecord objects, sorted by a date of some kind.

```
@array = (Bucket.all + Mop.all + Detergent.all).sort{|x,y| x.sort_by <==> y.sort_by}
```

Since your sort_by field is different for each object type, you need to define it.

```
class Bucket < ActiverRecord::Base
  def sort_by
    cleaned_on
  end
end

class Detergent < ActiverRecord::Base
  def sort_by
    purchased_on
  end
end
```

You could pull in all the data sorted in a single query using UNION, but you wouldn't get AR objects out of that.